# Matching list symbols in regex (angular 2)

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am trying to match the list of symbols in regex but somehow the result is always returning with errors

symbol list =  !@#$+*{}?<>&’”[]=%^

```
    if (text.match('^[\[\]\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\/\<\>\=\?\@\[\]\{\}\\\\\^\_\`\~]+$')) { 
      this.specialChar = true;
    } else {
      this.specialChar = false;
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /^[[]!"#$%&'()*+,/<>=?@[]{}\\^_`~]+$/: Nothing to repeat
```

How do I correctly match the symbols in regex? basically I want to check if text contain any of those symbols.

Comment: You want to match the whole chars or at least one of them?

Comment: I see a string, not a regular expression. I would expect to see `...match(/^...../)`

Comment: least one of them so if  text = 'some text + sometext' the expression should return true since '+' was in the text

Comment: In your string literal, all backlashes that do not form a valid escape sequence with the subsequent char get removed. You need to double escape them, or better use a *regex literal*.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this regex constructor instead:

```
   if (text.match(/^[\[\]\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\/\<\>\=\?\@\[\]\{\}\\\\\^\_\`\~]+$/)) { 
      this.specialChar = true;
    } else {
      this.specialChar = false;
    }
```

The reason it fails is that you use a regex string constructor. If you still want to do that, you need to `DOUBLE` escape the characters, like this:

```
if (text.match('^[\\[\\]\\!\\"\\#\\$\\%\\&\\'\\(\\)\\*\\+\\,\\/\\<\\>\\=\\?\\@\\[\\]\\{\\}\\\\\\^\\_\\`\\~]+$')) {
```

Now you will create a valid regex.